# Verifying Dropdown options my script is throwing an error pls help Webdriver and C#

Tags: c#, webdriver

Verifying Dropdown options my script is throwing an error pls help Webdriver and C#

two errors returned ; expected on the options ( for(IWebElement title:options))

```
public void VerifyDropdownOptions()
{
  String[] SysViews = {
  "--Select a view--",
  "Contacts being followed",
  "Contact I follow",
  "Contacts: No campaign activities in last 3 months",
  "Contacts: Responded to Campaigns in last 6 months",
  "Inactive contacts","My Connections"
};

IWebElement dropdown = FindElement(By.Id("crmGrid_SavedNewQuerySelector"));  

     SelectElement select = new SelectElement(dropdown);  

     List<IWebElement> options = select.getOptions();  
    // List<IWebElement> options = select.FindElements(By.LinkText("title"));  

     int SysOptions = SysViews.Length;

  for(IWebElement title:options)  

     {  
      Boolean match = false;

         for (int i=0; i < SysOptions; i++)

          {
              if (title.getText().equals(SysViews[i]))
                {
                match = true;
                }
          }
       Assert.True(match);
     }   
   }
```

Comment: The following error returned (; expected) on the   for (IWebElement title:options) highlighting option with the red line

Answer (score 0):

You are using C# use below code for foreach loop:

```
foreach (IWebElement title in options)
{ 

}
```

: is use for java not C#

Comment: Thank you very much Sadik will make changes and rerun